# Trouble with pointer arrays and attempting to resize

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Before anything, let me say this is for an assignment and I am not allowed to use Vectors.

What I'm attempting to do is resize 2 pointer arrays that contain objects. Array custArray has 3 elements and array gArray has 1. I need to move one specific object from custArray to gArray and remove it from custArray (so they both have 2 elements), so I have created 2 temporary arrays to change, then eventually set to equal custArray and gArray.

```
void setPreferred(string id, int cSize, int pSize, Customer *custArray, Gold *gArray)
{
   int count = 0;
   Customer *temp1 = new Customer[cSize - 1];
   Gold *temp2 = new Gold[pSize + 1];
   *temp2 = *gArray;
   for(int i = 0; i < cSize; i++)
      {
         if(custArray[i].getID() == id)
            {
               temp2[pSize].setName(custArray[i].getFirstName(), custArray[i].getLastName());
               temp2[pSize].setID(custArray[i].getID());
               temp2[pSize].setTotal(custArray[i].getTotal());
               temp2[pSize].setDiscount(0.5);
               //cout << temp2[1].getName() << " " << temp2[1].getID() << " " << temp2[1].getTotal() << " " << temp2[1].getDiscount() << endl;
            }

         if (custArray[i].getID() != id)
            {
               temp1[count].setName(custArray[i].getFirstName(), custArray[i].getLastName());
               temp1[count].setID(custArray[i].getID());
               temp1[count].setTotal(custArray[i].getTotal());
               count++;
            }
      }
   //cout << temp1[0].getName() << " " << temp1[0].getID() << " " << temp1[0].getTotal() << endl;
   //cout << temp1[1].getName() << " " << temp1[1].getID() << " " << temp1[1].getTotal() << endl;

   delete [] custArray;
   delete [] gArray;

   *custArray = *temp1;
   *gArray = *temp2;
}
```

The 2 original arrays are defined down in main as

```
Customer *customerArray = new Customer[customerSize];
Gold *goldArray = new Gold[preferredSize];
```

Arrays temp1 and temp2 work fine in the function, the cout statements print all the correct information. However, when I try to print in main any members of customerArray[1], it displays the incorrect information and members of goldArray[1] throw a bad_alloc error. I suppose that means there's something wrong with how I delete or reassign the arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `*custArray = *temp1;` and `*gArray = *temp2;` do not change the pointers; they only copy assign the first element from `temp1`/`temp2` to `custArray`/`gArray`  (which has been deleted in a previous statement). You need a way to pass the new pointer values to the caller of your function. Either pass the arguments by reference, or return the new values in a pair or a tuple.

Comment: Also, even if you are not using vectors, you can always create your own abstractions, and benefit from some encapsulation. In your case for example, you can pack an array and its size in a custom class (so that you don't have to deal with these related parameters separately).

Comment: There are lots of problems with your code but the fundamental one is that you want the function to return new arrays, but at no point do you return the new arrays. You seem to think that `*custArray = *temp1;` somehow copies the array from `temp1` to `custArray` but it doesn't. `*custArray = *temp1;` is **exactly** the same as `custArray[0] = temp1[0];`.

Comment: Do you know what *references* are, and how to pass arguments by reference? If not then I suggest that's your next chapter to study.

Comment: So I know to pass the arrays by reference, I would have to put an & next to their name in the function's parameters. However, because the statements I have only affect the first elements of the arrays I am still a bit lost on how to properly set the values of custArray[2] and gArray[2].

EDIT: This function was called by another function, so if I sort of daisy chained the array paramaters by passing them all by reference, would I eventually be able to change both elements?

Comment: @Siroos You need to pass by reference, and then somewhere in your code you need to write `custArray = temp1;` not `*custArray = *temp1;`

Comment: If you pass by reference (but remember that the order between `&` and `*` matter) then just use plain assignment. As in `custArray = temp1`.

Comment: @Siroos Always, *always*, when beginners get confused about pointers, it's because they confuse the pointer, with what the pointer is pointing to. That's exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Yep, just started learning about pointers so that's the case.

Comment: @Siroos And to answer your daisy chain question, yes if you use references all the way down it should work. Not that that is necessarily good style. Remember you can always **return** a pointer instead of passing by reference. Though this is a bit awkward when you are trying to change two pointers.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to where I would set `custArray = temp1`, as wouldn't anywhere besides my setPreferred function be out of its scope and thus it would be inaccessible?

Comment: Again this is a confusion between the pointer and what the pointer is pointing to. The variable `temp1` goes out of scope, but what it is pointing to is dynamically allocated memory, that never goes out of scope (until you delete it).

Comment: So, could I make a pointer to the pointer of *temp1, which I could them pass down by reference to eventually change custArray in, say, main?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, there's no need for pointers to pointers, only references to pointers. Just think of it like this, suppose you wanted to write a function which changed the value of an `int`, passed into the function by reference. Now write exactly the same code, only change the `int` to a pointer. It will work in the same way. That's the other rule about pointers, there's nothing special about pointers. They work in the same way as any other kind of variable.

Comment: Classic off-by-one error.   `temp1` is allocated as an array of `cSize-1` objects.   The loop manipulates `cSize` objects of that array.   In the last loop iteration, it is manipulating a non-existent object past the end of the array, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @john Just spouting off ideas, I suppose that one's wrong. So far, all I've changed is my parameters in `setPreferred` to `Customer *&custArray` and `Gold *&gArray` so that they're now passed by reference. After that, I think I'm pretty lost despite what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @Siroos I've answered the question with an outline of how the code should look.

Comment: @john well thank you for all the help :)
I'm just a bit confused on where exactly I'd put `custArray = temp1` but I'm sure I'll figure it out

Comment: @Siroos At the end, like I've shown you. Why would you put it anywhere else?

Comment: @Siroos I think you are still confusing copying the pointer and copying what the pointer is pointing to. `custArray = temp1;` copies the pointer, it doesn't copy what the pointer is pointing to. You still have to write the code to copy the array contents.

Comment: @john you know what- you're abosultely right, that works, I simply didn't update some of my `cout` statements to check. I'm terribly sorry about the whole misunderstanding there- I 100% understand what you mean now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Siroos Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dereference a pointer after it has been deleted.  If you do that, unexpected things may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `*custArray = *temp1` just copies single value, pointed by `temp1` and not  the rest (`temp1+1`, `temp1+2`, and so on). You have to do assignment in loop to copy array, but semantically you should NOT do this here.

You also delete storage that was pointed by `custArray` before you try to write to it, which is an UB.

You have on-off error by iterating through array of `cSize - 1` objects. Your `Customer` class is either obviously uncopyable, or you for some reason use getters\setters to copy individual fields instead of copy assignment. Makes me wonder if you even know how struct\class assignment works.

Secondly, `custArray` is local variable in way how you defined function parameters and you didn't change value outside of function. Passing pointer by reference  `Customer *&` (or C-style `Customer**`) would solve this, but it's ugly and makes code complex and error-prone. Reallocation changes memory storage and you have to return pointer to the new storage

I implore you to create class, specialized to work with array of `Customer` or `Gold`, or which is better, some generic `Array` template to work with any element class and implement basic assignment\move\allocation\deallocation logic inside of it. You writing C++ code, not C code, so ban on particular standard language component means you have to learn how implement your own, not just throw away it and pretend that it is an impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

In outline this is how your code should look

```
// note custArray and gArray passed by reference
void setPreferred(string id, int cSize, int pSize, Customer*& custArray, Gold&* gArray)
{
    // allocate the new arrays
    Customer *temp1 = new Customer[cSize - 1];
    Gold *temp2 = new Gold[pSize + 1];

    // code to do the copying from custArray and gArray to temp1 and temp2
    // (you still need to write this)
    ...

    // delete the old arrays
    delete[] custArray;
    delete[] gArray;

    // return the new arrays to the caller
    custArray = temp1;
    gArray = temp2;
}
```